# Cannot delete sharepoint app due to an error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I clicked cancel when app was updating and this caused "Sorry, something went wrong with updating the app. Click to retry." error. When I click retry, cancellation process begins, but couple of seconds after the same error pops up. There are no options to fully remove an application or update or anything of that sort. And since the application is technically "installed", I can not install it again.

What do to do next? please help!